# Cannot set DPMS timeouts on login to Debian/GNOME

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gnome

I am moving from the KDE desktop to GNOME. One of the features that wasn't working on GNOME was turning off the monitor after a timeout (not via screensaver).

I currently have everything configured and working so that xset dpms 300 600 900 command works Had to switch from GNOME Wayland to Xorg version to get it working. I put the command in a Bash file and on the Activities dock. Everything runs fine if run at the cli or as an Activity.

I am currently trying to execute the bash file on login. To try to accomplish that I have tried executing it from .bash_startup, setting it up as a Startup Application via Tweaks and executing it from .gnomerc. The results are always the same Standby=000, Suspend=000, Off=000.

I am running Debian 10 (current patch level), GNOME 3.30. I could use some suggestions, at least I can run the bash shell script after shutdown/restart/login.

Thanks for the help.
Mitch